# upload image files from my computer to Google Drive accont

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I am making an Desktop app in c# .net using Google drive Api. I  want to create folder in Google drive and want to upload images from my computer to that folder , please reply me as i am new to Google drive , waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need to know is at https://developers.google.com/drive/

Specifically you'll be using https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Comment: As i have done with uploading images to my Google drive account and now i want to upload video to my account ...how to do this?

Comment: Video and image are identical